# Python: get windows OS version and architecture

Tags: python, windows, cpu-architecture

First of all, I don't think this question is a duplicate of
[Detect 64bit OS (windows) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208828/detect-64bit-os-windows-in-python)
because imho it has not been thoroughly answered.

The only approaching answer is:

> Use `sys.getwindowsversion()` or the existence of PROGRAMFILES(X86)  (`if 'PROGRAMFILES(X86)' in os.environ`)

But:

- Does the windows environment variable `PROGRAMFILES(X86)` reliable? I fear that anyone can create it, even if it's not present on the system.
- How to use `sys.getwindowsversion()` in order to get the architecture?

Regarding `sys.getwindowsversion()`:
The link http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getwindowsversion
leads us to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28VS.85%29.aspx
but I don't see anything related to the architecture (32bit/64bit).
Moreover, the platform element in the returned tuple seems to be independent of the architecture.

One last note: I'm looking for a solution using both python 2.5 and a windows version starting at Windows XP

Thanks!

Edit:
The relevant info is available here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724340%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
but how can I get this with python?

Edit2:
On a 64bit windows, with a 32bit python interpreter:

- os.environ["PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"] returns

  - 'x86'
- platform.architecture() returns

  - ('32bit', 'WindowsPE')

Comment: What do you want to know, exactly? The size of the architecture or the place where programs are stored?

Comment: As the question title says: size of architecture and version

Comment: Tjese answeres are correct and the solution too, its just if you run an 32bit programm on 64 bit, windows emulates these data. So the winapi returns an incorrect version for you.

Comment: I'm looking for correct answers independently of the python interpreter target architecture. It's the OS architecture than I'm looking for.

Comment: architecture only subset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491391/is-there-a-reliable-way-to-determine-the-system-architecture-using-python 32 vs 64 subset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These variables show your current runtime status on windows:

```
@rem Test environment using this table:
@rem
@rem Environment Variable       32bit Native    64bit Native    WOW64
@rem PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE     x86             AMD64           x86
@rem PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432     undefined       undefined       AMD64
@rem
```

Comment: Sounds good! Do you know if a user can alter these environment variables (event unconsciously)?

Answer (score 26):

I think the platform module is really the best way to get this info.

```
  >>> import platform
  >>> platform.platform()
  'Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1'
  platform.processor()
  'Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel'
```

I don't see where to get a firm answer on 32/64 bit windows from here, so I suggest this:

```
  try:
      os.environ["PROGRAMFILES(X86)"]
      bits = 64
  except:
      bits = 32
  print "Win{0}".format(bits)
```

or, if you need to know which flavor of Python you are running (as you can run x32 python under x64 Windows):

```
x32 python x64 windows:
>>> platform.architecture()
('32bit', 'WindowsPE')
>>> sys.version
'2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]'

x64 python x64 windows:
>>> platform.architecture()
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
>>> sys.version
'2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

Comment: `platform.machine()` now returns 32/64 bit as `i386/AMD64`.

`platform.uname()` will return the OS version and architecture in a single call.

Comment: Python 3.10 for `platform.machine()` returns either `x86`, or `AMD64` (in Windows 10)

Answer (score 2):

1 Another option (poll WMI for OsArchitecture):

If you install [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) and the [python wmi](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html) module on top you should be able to do (but only from Windows Vista and up!):

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
for os in c.Win32_OperatingSystem():
    print os.osarchitecture
```

2 Alternatively you could also use the `_winreg` [module](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html) to check for the existence of `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (this is supposedly [only there](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/internals-and-architecture/what-s-the-wow6432node-under-the-hkey_local_machine-software-registry-subkey-.aspx) on 64 bit- OS versions) (no external dependencies).

Comment: unfortunately, pywin32 is not available for both python 2.5 and amd64 architecture  
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/

Comment: Ok, added another option (2) - untested since I have no 64 bit windows OS around.

Comment: Thanks Christophe, this should work indeed!
But I prefer a bit Luke's solution because I don't have to import a windows specific module

Answer (score 1):

i hope this can solve the problem 
i tried it on my windows 8.1 64 bit  and returns the value **AMD64** for me

```
import _winreg
def get_registry_value(key, subkey, value):

  key = getattr(_winreg, key)
  handle = _winreg.OpenKey(key, subkey )
  (value, type) = _winreg.QueryValueEx(handle, value)
  return value

windowsbit = get_registry_value(
    "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE",
    "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment",
    "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")
print windowsbit
```

just run this code
if you are working on 64 bit windows machine this will print AMD64

or if you are working on 32 bit it will print AMD32

i hope this code can help to solve this problem fully

Comment: This is the same as getting an environment variable. The only difference is it isn't affected by a SET command.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice Python command one-liner.

```
>python -c "import platform as p; print(p.platform());print(p.processor())"
Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
Intel64 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel

>
```