# How to compare a tuple return from a function within an if statement

Tags: python, function, if-statement, tuples

How would I compare an element of a tuple return from a function in an *if* statement?
For example, I would like to do something like the following...

```
if platform.machine() == "AMD64" :
```

This function only has one string varaible return. I would like to do the same except with platform.architecture() which has a return that looks like ('32bit', 'WindowsPE'). What I currently do is ...

```
architecture = platform.architecture()
if architecture[0] == "64bit":
```

I was wondering if there was something more pythonic that could be achieved in one line.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with just `if platform.machine()[0] == '64bit':`.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: please post this as answer as it's the pythonic one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, [`platform.architecture is unreliable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2209083/1903116), the best way to get the processor architecture would be

```
if platform.machine()[:-2] == "64":
    # 64 bit machine
else:
    # 32 bit machine
```

If you are really looking for the best way to use the value which you retrieved from a function, you can simply ignore other values and get only the values which you need using the index

```
def temp():
    return 1, "Welcome"
if temp()[1] == "Welcome":
    print 1
```