# I have a Win7 64bits OS, but the value of sys.platform is win32. Why?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

In Python3.4, I have:

```
>>>import sys
>>>print(sys.platform)
win32
```

But the system is absolutely of win64.

Here is a piece of code in tkinter__init__py:

```
import sys
if sys.platform == "win32":
    # Attempt to configure Tcl/Tk without requiring PATH
    from tkinter import _fix
```

which leads a ImportError to my code. The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "H:/User/Henri/WorkSpace/Python/DeepLearning/Try/Try01/Read_MNIST.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 98, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()   File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 28, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)   File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 8, in <module>
    import tkinter as Tk, tkinter.filedialog   File "D:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tkinter import _fix   File "D:\Python34\lib\tkinter\_fix.py", line 65, in <module>
    import _tkinter ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is invalid win32 application。
```

Comment: Python returns 'win32' for all versions of Windows for compatibility reasons.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208828/detect-64bit-os-windows-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do some fiddling around to determine if you're running in 64 or 32 bit windows.  See this question: [How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit mode on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os)

Python is very specific about what sys.platform returns for windows -> 'win32' or 'cygwin'

Determining the version of windows is up to you :D.

Comment: Thank you. I elaborate my problem with the system version issue. How can I overcome this import error of _tkinter? My python version is 3.4, and unfortunatly there is no matching tkinter module.