# Python: How to know if the OS/CPU is 64bits

Tags: python

Under Windows, I'm running a 32bits python.exe. I need to know if the OS/CPU is 64bits or 32bits.

My machine is running a Windows7 64bits.

Checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os), and tried to run this Python script:

```
import ctypes; print(32 if ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp)==4 else 64, 'bit CPU')
import sys; print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)
import struct; print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))
import platform; print( platform.architecture()[0] )
print( platform.machine() )
```

It outputs:

```
32 bit CPU
7fffffff False
32
32bit
AMD64
```

No proposal from the referenced post really gives you the CPU/OS architecture info. They all report 32bits because I'm running a Python 32bits binary.

How can I determine if the CPU/OS is 32bits or 64bits in a portable way (could loopu for 64 string in platform.machine() but I doubt that's the good way)?

Comment: So why doesn't `AMD64` tell you this? In a 32-bit binary, the other values all definitely should be 32-bits, that's entirely normal. Either `AMD64` or `x86_64` should both tell you that the CPU is 64-bit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, it tells me that, but is doing `is_64 = (platform.machine().find( "64" ) != -1)` a portable way to check? Will that work on all CPU/OS which are 64bits?

Comment: It works on 3 different architectures I tried (one of which is a VM).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: OK, that could be an acceptable answer than.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most information you are querying is determined by the wordsize of the interpreter, not the CPU.

Only `platform.machine()` ignores this information; it is taken from the system `uname -m` data instead, which is the recommended command to determine if your system is 64-bit for both [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246007/how-to-determine-whether-a-given-linux-is-32-bit-or-64-bit) and [OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/07/how-to-tell-if-youre-running-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-kernel-in-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/), and Windows provides the exact same information (Python uses the C `uname()` function in all cases).

Either test for `64` in that string, or build a set of acceptable values:

```
'64' in platform.machine()
```

or

```
platform.machine() in {'x86_64', 'AMD64'}
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/12578715/4124672

You may want to use this solution for python2.7 and newer:

```
def is_os_64bit():
    return platform.machine().endswith('64')
```