# Sublime Text output incorrect architecture

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

### 1. Summary

I have 64-bit Windows. But if I use [**`platform.architecture()[0]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2209083/5951529) or [**`sublime.arch()`**](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime) in my Sublime Text plugin, I get `32bit` value.

---

### 2. Settings

I create a file `ExampleSashaPlugin.py` in `$packages/TestPlugin` folder. Content of this file:

```python
import platform
import sublime

get_bitness = platform.architecture()[0]
print(get_bitness)

get_bitness_2 = sublime.arch()
print(get_bitness_2)
```

---

### 3. Steps to reproduce

I reproduce the problem in a version of Sublime Text without plugins and user settings.

I save `ExampleSashaPlugin.py`.

---

### 4. Expected behavior

If I get Windows bitness in Python interpreter:

```python
>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()[0]
'64bit'
```

---

### 5. Actual behavior

Sublime Text console output:

```python
key evt: control+s
command: save
reloading plugin TestPlugin.ExampleSashaPlugin
32bit
x32
```

---

### 6. Environment

**Operating system and version:**
Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 64-bit EN
**Sublime Text:**
Build 3126 portable for Windows 64-bit

Thanks.

Comment: did you install the 32bit version of Sublime Text maybe?

Comment: @KeithHall: [**no**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43511526/revisions). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Answer

As [**Keith Hall say**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/74076867), I had 32-bit Sublime Text in my 64-bit machine. I need use Sublime Text 64-bit for correct working `platform.architecture()` and `sublime.arch()` methods.

I don't understand, why I had 32-bit Sublime Text. I download `Sublime Text Build 3126 x64.zip` file — 64-bit portable version [**from official site**](https://www.sublimetext.com/3). Perhaps, in Sublime Text site posted an incorrect version, when I download 64-bit version.

---

### 2. Migrate to 64-bit version

If you also have 32-bit Sublime Text version in 64-bit PC by some reasons, you can solve the problem use these actions.

1. Create backup copy your Sublime Text, if something goes wrong.
2. [**Download last 64-bit version**](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) from official site.
3. Copy these files from new 64-bit Sublime Text root directory to root Sublime Text directory, that you will use:

   - `crash_reporter.exe`,
   - `msvcr100.dll`,
   - `plugin_host.exe`,
   - `python33.dll`,
   - `subl.exe`,
   - `sublime_text.exe`,
   - `update_installer.exe`.

Actually for April 2017.